# Install .wgt file on tizen TV with USB

Tags: android, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I have hard time installing .wgt file on TV with USB. App works normally on emulator. I have all required certificates. My distributor certificate has public privilege level with DUID of my emulator and my tv (where I want to test my app). In my USB root i created userwidget folder and copied .wgt file in it. When I plug USB in tv it detects it but after a few seconds I get message something like this: Installation with USB package is failed.
I have tried almost everything and I am running out of ideas what could be wrong. I assume is something with certificates/permissions but don't know what. My tv model is UE48J5570.

Updated:
I have also developer mode enabled on tv and signed in as develop user.

Comment: Is there any way to install .wgt file on tv? I have same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

USB installation is no longer supported on Tizen TVs.  The only way to run is through the IDE.

[Forum Post](https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/3ad8bd6023af18a7?forumID=37f03b7e17da2560):

> Hello.
>
> USB installation of application is abandoned from new firmware.
>
> You should use SDK and developer mode to run application.
>
> http://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3511/index.html

Comment: Links are no longer valid.